# Excel Addin - Visual studio - Files stucked on a given version when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, excel-addins

I'm developing an Excel Web Addin using Javascript API within Visual Studio 2022.
Everything was going well but now for some reason that I don't understand when debugging all the files got stuck on a given version. When I update some file and the run the project, in Excel the addin files remain the same (obsolete previous version).
Confirmed by "Inspect" Tool / Sources

Tryied:

- Cleaning & Rebuild
- Delete obj & bin folder

Any clue?
Tanks

Comment: For now, I've moved the project folder to a folder not synced by OneDrive, created a new project and copied the relevant files to that project. all seams back again.... Still not knowing what happened